# How to avoid ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump() from printing / / in between yaml key value

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

```
- name: Java_opts
  value: " -blablabla -blablabla -blablabla -blablabla -blablabla"
```

I have a key value similar to above, in yaml file.
When I dumping using ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump() and preserve_quotes it is adding // in between the string. Shown below

```
- name: Java_opts  
  value:" -blablabla -blablabla // - blablabla -blablabla // -blablabla"
```

How to avoid printing ----> //

Comment: How is PyYAML involded in this? Please indent code and data blocks 4 (four) spaces so the are properly displayed (select the block and press Ctrl+K)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using `ruamel.yaml.round_trip()` it is deprecated. Use `.load()` on an instance of YAML instead.

The other thing you want to do is provide valid YAML, and a full, minimal working program. Because your example is not YAML.
This is because the first element of the root level sequence is a dict (with key 'name') and the second element is
a scalar because there is no space after the first colon.

If you insert a space after after `value:` then everything should work fine::w

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- name: Java_opts
  value: " -blablabla -blablabla - blablabla -blablabla -blablabla"
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- name: Java_opts
  value: ' -blablabla -blablabla - blablabla -blablabla -blablabla'
```

Comment: Hi @Anthon, what if I want out put with double quotes?

Comment: Then you read the ruamel.yaml documentation and see that you can set `yaml.preserve_quotes=True`. Although you of course know that it doesn't make difference if you use a YAML loader to the loaded data, and it is better to use single quotes when double quotes are not necessary (as in your case).